# Django No records found on query

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to filter web search results of apartments on django3 but it doesn't matter what I put on the filters while filling the form, It shows the message "no records found" no mater how do I fill the form.
The database is already populated.

**my views.py**

```
def apartments_list(request):

    name = request.GET.get('name')
    address = request.GET.get('address')
    status = request.GET.get('status')
    price_range = request.GET.get('price_range')
    no_of_person = request.GET.get('no_of_person')
    bed_type = request.GET.get('bed_type')

    query = Q()
    if name:
        query &= Q(title__icontains=name)
    if address:
        query &= Q(apartmentaddress__city__icontains=address)
    if no_of_person and no_of_person.isdigit():
        query &= Q(persons=int(no_of_person))

    if bed_type:
        query &= Q(bed=bed_type)
    if price_range:
        min_price = price_range.split('-')[0]
        max_price = price_range.split('-')[1]

        query &= Q(price__gte=min_price)
        query &= Q(price__lte=max_price)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    apartments = Apartment.objects.filter(query).order_by('price')

    paginator = Paginator(Apartment.objects.filter(query), 10)
    try:
        apartments = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        apartments = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        apartments = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {}
    context['apartments'] = apartments
    context['name'] = name
    context['address'] = address
    context['no_of_person'] = no_of_person
    context['bed_type'] = bed_type
    context['price_range'] = price_range
```

My models.py

```
class Apartment(models.Model):

    APARTMENT_CHOICES = (
        ("Available", "Available"),
        ("Booked", "Booked")
    )

    clean_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    inspected_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apartment_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, choices=APARTMENT_CHOICES, default='Available')
    services = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    bed = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    price = models.IntegerField()
    persons = models.IntegerField()

    category = models.ForeignKey(ApartmentCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        ApartmentOwner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    title_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='apartments')

    description = RichTextField()

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        from apartments.models import ApartmentAddress
        apartment_address = ApartmentAddress.objects.filter(apartment=self)

        if apartment_address.count():
            name = "pass"

        return f'{self.title} - {self.bed} '

    def apartment_images(self):
        from apartments.models import ApartmentImage

        for i in ApartmentImage.objects.filter(apartment=self):
            print(i.image.url)

        return ApartmentImage.objects.filter(apartment=self)
```

If somebody can help me with this, I will appreciate it

Comment: You can view the produced query by checking `apartments.query`. You will maybe find the issue in the statement.

Comment: The result was: '''(AND: ('title__icontains', '  '), ('apartmentaddress__city__icontains', '  '), ('bed', 'single'), ('price__gte', '100'), ('price__lte', '200'))''' which should work but it doesn't because it doesn' t display anything because there are apartments that fulfill the condition. Maybe it' s a syntax error?

Comment: With a syntax error the query/code would not run. I suspect that you filter for data that does not exist.